# UITableViewCell isn't accessible with standard method?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm working on a project which has a controller, `Controller`, which holds all the logic (i.e. is the `UITableViewDelegate`). I have a view, `View1` which is a subclasses `UIView` containing a `UITableView` as a property.

My problem is that I want to update the first row (which is some sort of a header-row) when something happens. I thought I could do this call:

```
UITableViewCell* headCell = 
    (UITableViewCell*) [view1.tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

but this doesn't seem to work. my `headCell` is `(null)` when I `NSLog(@"%@", [headCell description]);`

My controller calls `[view1.tableView setDelegate:self]`, so I was also trying to call `[self cellForRow..]` but I just got unrecognized selector. The `NSIndexPath` should be correct, right?

I've tried to read up on this, but everyone seems to get cellForRowAtIndexPath to work, but I can't. Anyone got any ideas?

edit: I did a workaround instead, so can't really accept any answers without having tested them. Thanks though. The workaround was to create a cell that is referenced in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`-method and tweak it manually somewhere else. I know it's not best practice, but I don't have time to do otherwise right now. Thanks for contributions though, I'll check in later to test them and accept as answers if I can get it to work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NSNotification`

See the apple doc for [NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

it will be added by your header row and post it anywhere from application with the required data .

Comment: thanks for this - I think this is what I would've needed, but I don't have time to dig into it now. I promise I'll check it out later :) again; thanks

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method returns cell, if that cell is currently visible else it will return nil

Comment: in my case, it returns nil anyway... which is what I find very odd.

Comment: In your case, i think the cell you are trying to access is not visible at that time.

Comment: Well, it is. It simply isnt possible to hide that cell in my view.